# I need to only select the minimum value of my query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view created in SQL Server Management Studio that brings in certain data, I need to only select the rows with the minimum sequence. For example, in the screenshot see the job number "50773-4", I would only need to see the row with SEQ number 2. I've tried to Group by Min, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT
    TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Job_Operation.Job,
    MIN(dbo.Job_Operation.Sequence) AS SEQ,
    dbo.Job_Operation.Work_Center,
    dbo.Work_Center.Department
FROM
    dbo.Job_Operation
    INNER JOIN dbo.Job ON dbo.Job_Operation.Job = dbo.Job.Job
    INNER JOIN dbo.User_Values ON dbo.Job.User_Values = dbo.User_Values.User_Values
    INNER JOIN dbo.Work_Center ON dbo.Job_Operation.Work_Center = dbo.Work_Center.Work_Center
GROUP BY
    dbo.Job_Operation.Job,
    dbo.User_Values.Numeric2,
    dbo.Work_Center.UVText4,
    dbo.Job.Status,
    dbo.Job_Operation.Status,
    dbo.User_Values.Decimal1,
    dbo.Job_Operation.Work_Center,
    dbo.Work_Center.Department
HAVING
    (dbo.Work_Center.UVText4 = 'Machining')
ORDER BY
    dbo.User_Values.Decimal1 DESC,
    SEQ
```

[enter image description here]
[image: 1]

Comment: `TOP (100) PERCENT ... ORDER BY...` absolutely does not do what you think it does. Can I also gently suggest you use table aliases as this will make your life much easier

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
SELECT
    TOP (100) PERCENT Job,
    Sequence AS SEQ,
    Work_Center,
    Department
FROM
( select  dbo.Job_Operation.Job,
    dbo.Job_Operation.Sequence,
    dbo.Job_Operation.Work_Center,
    dbo.Work_Center.Department,
    dbo.User_Values.Decimal1 , 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by dbo.Job_Operation.Job,
                                    dbo.User_Values.Numeric2,
                                    dbo.Work_Center.UVText4,
                                    dbo.Job.Status,
                                    dbo.Job_Operation.Status,
                                    dbo.User_Values.Decimal1,
                                    dbo.Job_Operation.Work_Center,
                                    dbo.Work_Center.Department 
                                 Order by   dbo.Job_Operation.Sequence asc) rn
FROM
    dbo.Job_Operation
    INNER JOIN dbo.Job ON dbo.Job_Operation.Job = dbo.Job.Job
    INNER JOIN dbo.User_Values ON dbo.Job.User_Values = dbo.User_Values.User_Values
    INNER JOIN dbo.Work_Center ON dbo.Job_Operation.Work_Center = dbo.Work_Center.Work_Center
) tt
WHERE rn = 1
and UVText4 = 'Machining'
```

Comment: Getting this error when I run the code above. "Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
The column 'Job' was specified multiple times for 'tt'."

Comment: Oh then mention column names inside dubquwry instead of *

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
with
q as (
  SELECT
    dbo.Job_Operation.Job,
    MIN(dbo.Job_Operation.Sequence) AS SEQ,
    dbo.Job_Operation.Work_Center,
    dbo.Work_Center.Department,
    dbo.User_Values.Decimal1
  FROM
    dbo.Job_Operation
    INNER JOIN dbo.Job ON dbo.Job_Operation.Job = dbo.Job.Job
    INNER JOIN dbo.User_Values 
      ON dbo.Job.User_Values = dbo.User_Values.User_Values
    INNER JOIN dbo.Work_Center 
      ON dbo.Job_Operation.Work_Center = dbo.Work_Center.Work_Center
  GROUP BY
    dbo.Job_Operation.Job,
    dbo.User_Values.Numeric2,
    dbo.Work_Center.UVText4,
    dbo.Job.Status,
    dbo.Job_Operation.Status,
    dbo.User_Values.Decimal1,
    dbo.Job_Operation.Work_Center,
    dbo.Work_Center.Department
  HAVING
    (dbo.Work_Center.UVText4 = 'Machining')
),
r as (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by job order by seq) as rn
  from q
)
select job, seq, work_center, department
from r 
where rn = 1
order by Decimal1 DESC
```

Comment: Getting this error when I run the code above. "Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
The multi-part identifier "dbo.Job_Operation.Job" could not be bound."

Comment: I modified the query. Just use `job` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the RANK() window function.  Perhaps:

```
SELECT column1, 
          column2,
          rank() OVER (PARTITION BY job ORDER BY seq) AS seq_by_job
```

Then use this as a nested statement, and filter on only the min rank (i.e. WHERE nested_statement.seq_by_job = 1)